# How to read a Java String using BufferedReader's line.split method?

Tags: java, line, bufferedreader, split

I want to read a text file and store some of the required values as java Strings.

I am using Bufferedreader to read and store the values. I inserted a line where the line contains: Possible values will be

```
NAME: lastname, firstname *CONTRACTOR*
NAME:
NAME: Sapi, Raj J.
NAME: Alle Peter, Shortley Swara
```

From above I need only lastname and first name. Sometimes this value won't be there at all. In that case how can I validate whether the Name line has values or not? For this I am using the below code which is throwing Nullpointer Exception.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("CNUM")) {
            cnum = line.split(" ")[1];
            // break;
        }
        if (line.contains("NAME")) {
            name = line.split(" ")[2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: from which line its throwing NPE ?

Comment: @Rehman - Where I am checking line.contains("Name") .

Comment: No way. Check your line numbers again. And post the complete stack trace.

Comment: `line` cant be null because you already did a null check

Comment: @ Rehman, JB Nizet - Earlier it was throwing Nullpointer. Now I changed my code its throwing ArrayIndexOutofbounds exception. Sorry ...

Comment: Again..from which line ?

Comment: Just a guess:  Change `name = line.split(" ")[2];` to  `name = line.split(" ")[1];`

Comment: Can you confirm that when you split the line you have three elements (at least) in *every case*; Otherwise, this line `line.split(" ")[2];` will throw that exception

Comment: @ Rehman - line.split[2]. This is because sometimes Name contains values and some times no values

Comment: @ochi - No. It doesn't always contain values for Name line. For Some records no values will be there and for some records values will be like the above format: NAME: lastname, firstname *CONTRACTOR*

Comment: if Name contains no value than obviously get an exception , make sure you check for empty value for name

Comment: It might be useful to put up a snippet of data that you are reading.  Preferably a good representation of your data that represents all of the scenarios your code would run against.  E.g. short lines, long lines, possibly empty lines (if they occur) etc.

Comment: @Dale - there are the possible values of name line: NAME: lastname, firstname *CONTRACTOR* NAME: , NAME: Sapi, Raj J.

Comment: Okay.  Sounds good.  I was hoping for a bigger sample of data.  The sample of data might shine some light on what really is going on.

Comment: @Dale - Please check the possible values of Name. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may want something like this...

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("CNUM")) {
            cnum = line.split(" ")[1];
            // break;
        }
        if (line.trim().startsWith("NAME:")) {

            line = line.replace("NAME:", "");
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.contains(",")){
                String[] contractorName = line.split(",");
                String lastName = contractorName[0].trim();
                String firstName = contractorName[1].trim();
                // use the last name and first name as you wish here.
            } else {
                // line doesn't contain a first and last name for contractor.  invalid data.
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... will try this

Comment: Not sure. Still its showing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. Before this I tried printing out the first name and last name. Its printing properly. But after that giving this exception.

Comment: On what data element is it failing?  Can you step through the code and see what data element it is getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception.